# Cauchy's differentiation formula

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

I understand that $
\begin{align}
\oint_C (z-z_0)^n dz 
= \begin{cases}
2\pi i & \text{if } n = -1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$

And I understand that $
f^{(0)}(z)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma f(\xi)\frac{1}{\xi-z}d\xi$

Differentiating we get $ 
f'(z)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma f(\xi)\frac{1}{(\xi-z)^2}d\xi $

Clearly $n \neq -1$ So why is that last integral not zero?

Answer (score 1):

The last integral is not zero because there is an "$f$" in the integrand, which changes the integral substantially. For instance, if you throw away the $f$, you get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(\xi - z)^2}d\xi,$$
but we see that this is the integral with $f(\xi) = 1$ identically:
$$0 = \frac{d}{dz}1 = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma 1\frac{1}{(\xi - z)^2}d\xi.$$

In pariticular, if $\gamma$ is contour of the circle, with counter-clockwise orientation and $f(z) = z$, then $$1 = f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\gamma}f(\xi)\frac{1}{(\xi - 0)^2}d\xi = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{\xi}d\xi \neq 0.$$

Comment: The book I'm reading switches back and forth between $f(z)$ and $f(z_0)$. 1 minute it treats it as a function and the next minute it treats it as a constant.

Comment: $\int_{C_r}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz = \int_{C_r}\frac{f(z_0)}{z-z_0}dz + \int_{C_r}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}dz = f(z_0)2\pi i + 0$

Answer (score 0):

Because of the presence of $f(\xi)$ there. You can't jump from$$\oint_C(\xi-z)^{-2}\,\mathrm d\xi=0\text{ to }\oint_Cf(\xi)(\xi-z)^{-2}\,\mathrm d\xi=0.$$